# Is digging a "cold hole" really effective when sheltering in a snowed area?

Tags: snow, shelter

One recommendation I got in case of emergency or intentional sheltering in a snowy location is to dig a lower hole, so that the cold air can move there, while one can sleep higher up where the heat stays. I understand the physics involved, but I am not aware of how much difference it can do in practice. How many degrees are we talking here ? Is it really recommended, or does it just waste energy ?

Comment: This also referred to as a "cold air sump".

Answer (score 32):

Doing it correctly can ensure the temperature of the snow cave maintains around 32°F (0°C) or higher.

Its not just about digging the extra hole but how the entire cave is constructed that can make the difference between life and death.

Here's the general idea.

[image]

Of course doing this won't guarantee your safety, but it sure helps.

To answer your question directly, it makes a huge difference and is absolutely recommended.

**EDIT**
As pointed out in the comments, we should always give credit to those from whom we get information from.

Source: [Mike Clelland](http://littleboingmarks.blogspot.com/search/label/instructional)

Comment: Good use of a Mike Clelland drawing :)

Comment: Can we credit the authors on this use of their work please! It's a great book and I think many people would like to read it... [Allen and Mike's Really Cool Backcountry Ski Book](http://www.amazon.com/Allen-Really-Backcountry-Revised-Better/dp/0762745851) They are two NOLS instructors who have done a great job getting information out there to the masses. Bios - (http://www.linkedin.com/in/alleno), (http://littleboingmarks.blogspot.com/)

Comment: You are right, I should have. I pulled it from google images without looking for where it came from.

Comment: 32 degrees???? That would melt all immediatelly... Aaaah, you must mean 32 degrees Fahrenheit, not Celsius! Right?

Comment: I have recently created a Wikipedia article on this topic: [Cold hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_hole). We're talking 2016, so either people just don't know about this practice (and I mean Wikipedia, duh!) – or I'm using my words wrong, and the article already exists under a different title. I'm no hiking enthusiast (let alone mountaineer or climber), but I love the physics rationale – so I need help here from someone with an actual drive to set things right. Long story short: help! :)